# Django tests getting error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to prepare some simple tests for my app. I have a model as below:

```
class Kategoria(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField('Nazwa Kategorii', max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kategoria"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kategorie"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```

In the tests.py:

```
import unittest
from blog.models import Kategoria

class KategoriaTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.nazwa = 'Nowa_kategoria'

    def test_tworzenie_obiektu(self):
        tworzenie_nowej_kategoria=Kategoria.objects.create(self.nazwa)
        self.assertTrue(tworzenie_nowej_kategoria)
        self.assertEqual(nowa_kategoria.nazwa,'Nowa_kategoria')
```

On the end test fails because:

> TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[**`create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#create) takes  keywords arguments.

In your `test_tworzenie_obiektu` method change

```
tworzenie_nowej_kategoria = Kategoria.objects.create(self.nazwa)
                                                     ^^^^
```

to

```
 tworzenie_nowej_kategoria = Kategoria.objects.create(nazwa=self.nazwa)
```

So you method should be

```
def test_tworzenie_obiektu(self):
        tworzenie_nowej_kategoria = Kategoria.objects.create(nazwa=self.nazwa)
        self.assertTrue(tworzenie_nowej_kategoria)
        self.assertEqual(nowa_kategoria.nazwa,'Nowa_kategoria')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the field name with `create()`, like this:

```
def test_tworzenie_obiektu(self):
    tworzenie_nowej_kategoria = Kategoria.objects.create(nazwa=self.nazwa)
    self.assertTrue(tworzenie_nowej_kategoria)
    self.assertEqual(nowa_kategoria.nazwa,'Nowa_kategoria')
```

You should also confirm the last `self.assertEqual`, it will always fail since there is no `nowa_kategoria` variable in your class; you probably want

```
self.assertEqual(tworzenie_nowej_kategoria.nazwa, self.nazwa)
```

Note that I removed the hardcoded name, and changed the name of the variable to that of the object being returned.